# No matching function call to State::State (State )

Tags: c++

I dont know why this calling for the copy Constructer in class Node   give this error , although class State copy constructer work in the main ,  take a look .

Note:my compiler is gcc version 4.8.2 .

```
class Node
{
public:
  Node(Node& rhs);
  Node(State state);

private:
  State mystate;
  Node* next;  // pointer to the next node
};



Node::Node(Node& rhs) : mystate(rhs.getState()), next(NULL)
{
  // the error  here  how ever I could call
  // State cpy constructer in main or other places ! 
}

Node:: Node(State state): mystate(state) , next(NULL)
{
  //....
}



class State
{
public:
  State(State& RHS);
  void operator = (State& RHS);

private:
  State* parent;


  State::State(State& RHS) : parent(NUL)
  {
    .....
  }

  void State::operator = (State& RHS)
  {
  }

};



int main()
{
  State x;
  State m = x; //  here State cpy constructer called successfuly
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use TAB characters in markup code representation! Correct the rest of the edits yourself please (too tired now).

Comment: `class Node`'s definition should not even compile because it uses the undeclared identifier `State`. To fix this, `State` must be defined first (not just declared either).

Answer (score 1):

Note that the compiler must see a declaration **before** a constructor is used. However, you declare the `State` class **after** the `Node` class. By the time the compiler reaches `main()` it has seen the copy ctor, so it won't complain.

One way to fix this is to move the `State` declaration before the `Node` declaration.

A better fix is to move your class declarations into a `.h` file and keep your function definitions in the `.cpp` file. Just `#include` the `.h` file at the top of the `.cpp` file so that all declarations are visible throughout the `.h` file.

Generally in large projects you will want to organize your code into `.h` and `.cpp` files in order to manage declarations and definitions and the dependencies between them.

Comment: every class in it's header file bro

Comment: @AbuGaseem That's certainly one way to organize your code but not required. This isn't Java.

Comment: so what the solution ... , my code is orgnized in my project

Comment: @AbuGaseem Your post makes it look like all of your code is in one file. If you already have separated code into `.h` files, you need to indicate which parts of your code are in which files. Until we know your project structure, we cannot provide any further help.

Comment: ok here's the set of  include main contain Node.h  ,
State.cpp contain State.h , Node.cpp contain Node.h 
,how ever the problem solved if i return the address of the State rather the value ,but this not natural !.

Comment: The reason that when  mystate(rhs.getState()) rhs.getState () return the value it will destruct it , and pass a NULL so that's the reason , do you suggest a solution for it  rather return it's address ?

Comment: @AbuGaseem Please edit your original question to include the description of the file structure. You should label each code snippet with the file name and post all #include directives.

Comment: " do you suggest a solution for it rather return it's address?" I don't understand what you are asking. You probably need to post a new question with the relevant code and a description of what is happening that you don't want.